# Replacing a value for JSON object in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I tried replacing the value for the key "Information" from the below JSON Object using the code

```
"itsmdata.incidentParamsJSON.IncidentContainerJson.replace("Information",option);"
```

but getting error as object is not defined (Attachment)[image: Error]

```
{
    "ServiceName": "IM_LogOrUpdateIncident",
    "objCommonParameters": {
        "_ProxyDetails": {
            "ProxyID": 0,
            "ReturnType": "JSON",
            "OrgID": 1,
            "TokenID": null
        },
        "incidentParamsJSON": {
            "IncidentContainerJson": "{\"SelectedAssets\":null,\"Ticket\":{\"Caller_EmailID\":null,\"Closure_Code_Name\":null,\"Description_Name\":\"Account Unlock\",\"Instance\":null},\"TicketInformation\":{\"Information\":\"account locked out\"},\"CustomFields\":null}"
        },
        "RequestType": "RemoteCall"
    }
}
```

Comment: incidentParamsJSON is inside objCommonParameters. you should use objCommonParameters.incidentParamsJSON. BTW you should not replace keys in object using replace

Comment: @Dineshundefined : I want to replace the value of that specific key " information"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to update properties of itsmdata you can try this

```
let str = itsmdata.objCommonParameters.incidentParamsJSON.IncidentContainerJson;
itsmdata.objCommonParameters.incidentParamsJSON.IncidentContainerJson = str.replace(/Information/gi, option);
```

Comment: Hi KibGZr, Thanks for your solution, now i am not getting the error but the new value is not getting replaced.